# Cloning blog to localhost via WAMP

Tags: database, mysql, localhost, clone-site

How do restore a Wordpress blog (actually, cloning would be the right word) from my server to localhost with WAMP?

I backed up my blog with [BackUpWordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backupwordpress/) and got a `.zip` file `sitename.backup.2012-01-29-12-50-08`. As per instructions, I unzipped the file and got a complete Wordpress installation (folders `wp-admin`, `wp-content`, a bunch of files, `.htaccess` etc.) and an SQL database named `database_myusername_wrdp2`.

I copied all the files except the database to WAMP's `www` folder.

Then I opened phpMyAdmin through WAMP, created a database named `wordpress`, opened that database and used Import button to import `database_myusername_wrdp2` to this new database.

Unfortunately, there is obviously no connection between the installation and a database as I get `Error establishing a database connection` message when I try to open `localhost`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I clone this blog locally?

Answer (score 1):

You must change the parameters to connect to the database in the file wp-config.php in the root folder of your Wordpress installation, or create the same user/password and database name for the database that you have created locally with WAMP.

Note:
You may have to change the blog_url and every url in the dump that refers to images/css in the posts , if you want to use it locally. You can do this via a find/replace in the SQL ( http://www.youronlinesite.com -> http://localhost) or in the SQL after you create the DB, see this [link](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/01/30/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/) for a list of useful queries

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

1. Install the plugin in the source and in destination (normal wordpress installation recently installed preferentially).
2. Export the site in the plugin in source, then import in the destination.
3. See the magic happens and be happy! :)